# Transform position not returning correct value

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this simple code:

```
GameObject newObj = Instantiate(loadAsset, transform);
newObj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(assetScale, assetScale, assetScale);
_container = newObj.transform;
_tooltip = _container.GetChild(1);

PositionCanvas();
Controls = true;

Debug.Log(newObj.transform.Find("Tooltip").rotation.eulerAngles);
Debug.Log(newObj.transform.Find("Tooltip").position);
```

According to the inspector mi position values are this ones:

[image]

But the Console returns me this:

[image]

Can anyone explain me what could i be doing wrong or why am i receiving (0, 1, 0) instead of (0, 100, 0)?

Comment: Are you familiar with world space and local space positions?

Comment: Yes... i just realized that i was seeing world coordinates instead of local coordinates and the parent had a 0.01 scale applied to it, thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

In the inspector, you are watching the local position and it's relative to the parent. The console presents the world position. My guess is your parent object is has either different position vector then (0,0,0) or a scale of 0.01 on the Y-axis.